# Zend Framework: hyperlink to execute script without leaving the webpage?

Tags: zend-framework

I am using Zend Framework to create a web application.
In some pages I have a link which is supposes to execute a script on the server when clicked. I do this by associating this link with an Action Controller.
What I want to do is when I click the link, the code in the action controller executes but without leaving the original page withing which i clicked the link

How to do this?

Please help .....

Comment: Use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to either execute an ajax controller than can render the appropriate controller/action based on some parameters, or have the Ajax call hit the controller/action directly and then do something with the response.  Javascript libraries like jQuery or Prototype have objects that do Ajax requests for you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use ajax since you want the action to get executed without leaving the page:

for example if you are using jquery :

```
$("#myLink").click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "/my/action", //your action
       data: "item="+item, //a value that you might want to send to your action
       success: function(html, msg){
           //do something on success
       }
     }); 
});
```

Comment: Is there any way I can click the link withou leaving the page without using ajax?

Comment: the only way i know to execute another action without reloading/leaving the current page is to use ajax

Answer (score 1):

there are ways to do this in php but you will need to do page refreshes.
this is one method I use to stay on the same page `$this->_redirect($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());` will take you back to the same page you made the request from, it will however cause a refresh of the page.
[_forward()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.utilmethods) will allow you to execute another action within the same request, so it may be of some use to you.
What you want to do can be done without ajax but you will have endure a certain number of page refreshes.

The action

```
 public function indexAction() {

        //get form and pass to view
        $form = new Admin_Form_Station();
        $form->setAction('/admin/index');
        $form->setName('setStation');

        $this->view->station = $this->_session->stationName;
        $this->view->stationComment = $this->_session->stationComment;
        $this->view->form = $form;

        try {
            //get form values from request object
            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

                if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {

                    $data = (object)$form->getValues();

                    //set session variable 'station'
                    $this->_session->station = $data->station;

                    //assign station name and comment to session
                    $station = new Application_Model_DbTable_Station();
                    $currentStation = $station->getStation($this->_session->station);
                    $this->_session->stationName    = $currentStation->station;
                    $this->_session->stationComment = $currentStation->comment;

                    //assign array() of stations to session namespace
                    $stations = $station->fetchAllStation();
                    $this->_session->stations = $stations;

                    //assign array() of bidlocations to session namespace
                    $bidLocation  = new Application_Model_DbTable_BidLocation();
                    $bidLocations = $bidLocation->fetchAllBidLocation($this->_stationId);
                    $this->_session->bidLocations = $bidLocations;

                    //display the same page with properties set
                    $this->_redirect($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
                }
            }
        } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
            //assign error to flash messenger...TODO not for production
            $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage($e->getMessage());
            //refresh the page and display message
            $this->_redirect($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
        }
    }
```

and in the view

```
<?php if (!$this->station): ?>
    <div class="span-5 prepend-2">
        <?php echo $this->form ?>
    </div>
    <div class="span-10 prepend-2 last">
        <p style="font-size: 2em">Please select the Station you wish to perform Administration actions on.</p>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="span-19 last">
        <?php echo $this->render('_station.phtml') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I found a solution that does seems to work. 
use your link in the view like normal, it calls and executes an action. In the action you are processing redirect back to the page you were viewing. The one thing to consider is that any temporary data will be lost, so a strategy to persist (session) any temporary data you need to keep would be important. I typically use Zend_Session_Namespace routinely to persist data. The code sample above is a good example of how I persist the data I need.
I have tested this in my own application and as long as the data remains available the page refreshes with no noticeable change in content or url.

Comment: I think this is a mistake: getRequestUri() returns the Uri to which i want to navigate to not the the Uri of the page from which i made the request, so the redirect in this request will enter in an infinite loop ( I tried this)

Comment: @AlaABUDEEB I'd like to see how you are trying to use $this->_redirect($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri()); I use this frequently with small forms to set parameters and to flash messages for success or errors.

Comment: aha, I understand your point, your method is only valid when using forms. but think of it a little bit, how to to this with a normal hyperlink that has no setAction() method, try it urself and u will get my point

Comment: I'll think on this, I'm sure I can figure something out.

Comment: @AlaABUDEEB what kind of action are you trying to process?

Comment: a normal action for a normal hyperlink.

Comment: a normal action for a normal hyperlink.
No form is in the page, it is just that this link is part of the layout, so it apears on all pages across the site. Well this link is associated with an action whose task is executing a system-level script ( php system() function ). So at this point, after executing the system() function, I want the link to take me to the same page in which i was, ( the link is only responsible of executing the system() function , it does not have to dispaly any thing, just stay on the same page). I think the idea is clear now! thank you